# Create a custom loop with post IDs taken from Magic Fields 2 duplicate text fields

Tags: arrays, wordpress, loops, foreach, posts

I'm trying to create a custom loop with content related to specific post IDs whose numbers I'm getting from a Magic Fields duplicate text field called "reference_posts".

When I echo $testvalue; it outputs the correct listing of posts "20432,43242,34253," but when I try to output it inside the array I only get the first value repeated over and over "20432,20432,20432,".

I'm guessing the problem is that I have to envelope the second foreach within the first but I'm not managing to do that.

Can anyone help me out?

```
<?php 
    $value  = get_field ('reference_posts') ;
    foreach ( $value  as  $my_val ) { 
    $testvalue = $my_val . ",";
    echo $testvalue;
    $post_idarray = array( 'post__in' => array( $testvalue ) );
    $postspecial = get_posts($post_idarray);
}
    foreach( $postspecial as $post ) :
    setup_postdata($post);  
    ?> 

<div>my content</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it with:

```
<?php 
    $value  = get_field ('reference_posts') ;
    foreach ( $value  as  $my_val );
    $args = array( 'include' => $value );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

<div>my content</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```